# Getting String input from the user and searching it in an array

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashmap

I need to get String input from the user and search it in some array and then i need to order the results like

1. The most similar thing
2. ....
3. ......

like user's input will be like "The mos" and it will show this as result.

This one was the method i wrote for it but i couldn't complete it:
(That is some homework and i need to use self-written data structures and i need to use a hashmap to create a phonebook. If you need my other classes i can update the question.)

```
  public static void searchByName()
        {
            System.out.println("Name: ");
            String nameSearch = input.next();
            for(int i=0; i < contactList.bucket.length; i++)
            {
                Iterator itr = (LinkedListIterator<HashEntry<Integer,Person>>) contactList.bucket[i].iterator(); 
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                HashEntry<Integer,Person> he = (HashEntry<Integer, Person>) itr.next();
                int similarity = nameSearch.compareTo(he.getValue().getName());
                HashEntry<Integer,String>[] similarArray = null;
                for(int x=0; x < contactList.bucket[i].size; x++)
                {
                    similarArray[x] = new HashEntry(similarity, he.getValue().getName()); 
                }//end of for loop

                }//end of while loop

            }//end of for loop

        }//end of searchByName
```

Comment: I'd like to see your indents fixed.

Comment: Thank you, I hope someone will help me

Comment: please clarify: do you want simple completion  of the input, do you want suggestions for corrections or do you want both?

Comment: What kind of help do you want? Do you know how you are going to tell which element is closest to the input? Do you need help with algorithm, output, something else?

Comment: @midor want the most similar values from the array. it will be a contact list so when you type some text information, it will show you the most similar ones as result. yeah there should be more than one result.

Comment: @realUser404 i don't know if my algorithm is correct but i was thinking about using String.compareTo() method to do that. I need help with algorithm i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think about how you are going to tell which elements are "similar" to the user's input.

Coming to my mind :

- Elements containing 1 or all words from input.
- Elements containing whole chain.
- Elements containing all letters, no care about order.

When you know what algorithm you want, implementing it should then be easy, but you **first need to ask yourself those questions before writting any code**.

Comment: i think it should show the elements containing 1 or all words from input or whole chain. thank you for your help

Comment: Then you just need to think about what you need to achieve that :
decompose input in array of words, decompose elements in array of words, and compare each word.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking like getting the similarity value by String.compareTo() method and then creating an "HashEntry" array which  assigns similarity value with the name and then somehow sorting that array with respect to similarity values and printing that array to the screen but i don't know how to achieve that. This code chunk above was all i could do.

Comment: Cannot help you more with that, you have all the keys to do the job. The problem here isn't technical, you just need to take a piece of paper and a pen, and start thinking about what you want to do. Once you do so everything with become smooth :)